# Maximal element for set of prime numbers with division as relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, prime-numbers, relations, order-theory

Set of all prime numbers $(P, |)$ (division operator as relation) is a poset. All elements are minimal element. In the same way all elements are maximal elements right? say m is maximal prime, then if m | p then p = m right?

But in class, professor told maximal elements are none(probably i might have understood wrongly or did something wrong). Please clarify

Comment: Yes, every member of $P$ is both minimal and maximal. Are you sure that he said *maximal* and not *maximum*? Because it’s true that $P$ has no *maximum* element in this order.

Comment: No sir, i was sleepy that time. So i am asking. I surely heard that all are minimal. But then i did not listen properly in case of maximal elements. After thinking i feel all are maximal. Since in a set all are maximal aswell as minimal elements. So i am surprised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your professor was indeed talking about the division operator on the set of prime numbers, then no prime number divides any other prime number, so every element of that set is both minimal and maximal and there's not much more to be said.

But I suspect that your professor, when making that statement about no maximal elements, was instead referring to the set of all natural numbers (or, perhaps, all integers). And indeed, no matter what natural number $n$ you pick, it is not maximal with respect to the division relation: certainly there exists a natural number $m \ne n$ such that $n$ divides $m$.

Comment: thank you sir. I understood now. Are there any other posets like this where all elements are both maximal as well as minimal elements

Comment: For every set, the equality relation on that set is a partial ordering in which all elements are both maximal as well as minimal.

Comment: thank you sir. ... IN these cases, hasse diagram will be set of isolated points(which are both maximal and miniaml elemnts each) in a line right? pls correct me if wrong

Comment: I would say it is just a set of isolated points without any structure at all, i.e. not in a line nor in any other particular shape.

Comment: understood now.